# Can't connect to Protonmail with JavaMail API

Tags: java, smtp, jakarta-mail

I've wrote a tiny Java program to send mails. It works when I try to send a mail from gmail but not from protonmail. Here is the code :

- [Main class](https://pastebin.com/ViwcN9G7)
- [MailSender class](https://pastebin.com/ByZpqpPN)
- [SmtpAuthenticator class](https://pastebin.com/zU9m9qCd)

And here is the logs :

```
DEBUG: JavaMail version 1.4.7
DEBUG: URL jar:file:/D:/Programmation/Java/Libraries/javamail-1.4.7/lib/gimap.jar!/META-INF/javamail.providers
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: jar:file:/D:/Programmation/Java/Libraries/javamail-1.4.7/lib/gimap.jar!/META-INF/javamail.providers
DEBUG: URL jar:file:/D:/Programmation/Java/Libraries/javamail-1.4.7/lib/imap.jar!/META-INF/javamail.providers
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: jar:file:/D:/Programmation/Java/Libraries/javamail-1.4.7/lib/imap.jar!/META-INF/javamail.providers
DEBUG: URL jar:file:/D:/Programmation/Java/Libraries/javamail-1.4.7/lib/pop3.jar!/META-INF/javamail.providers
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: jar:file:/D:/Programmation/Java/Libraries/javamail-1.4.7/lib/pop3.jar!/META-INF/javamail.providers
DEBUG: URL jar:file:/D:/Programmation/Java/Libraries/javamail-1.4.7/lib/smtp.jar!/META-INF/javamail.providers
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: jar:file:/D:/Programmation/Java/Libraries/javamail-1.4.7/lib/smtp.jar!/META-INF/javamail.providers
DEBUG: Tables of loaded providers
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Class Name: {com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Oracle], com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.gimap.GmailSSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,gimaps,com.sun.mail.gimap.GmailSSLStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.gimap.GmailStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,gimap,com.sun.mail.gimap.GmailStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Oracle]}
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Protocol: {imaps=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Oracle], imap=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Oracle], gimap=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,gimap,com.sun.mail.gimap.GmailStore,Oracle], smtps=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Oracle], pop3=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Oracle], smtp=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle], pop3s=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Oracle], gimaps=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,gimaps,com.sun.mail.gimap.GmailSSLStore,Oracle]}
DEBUG: URL jar:file:/D:/Programmation/Java/Libraries/javamail-1.4.7/lib/smtp.jar!/META-INF/javamail.address.map
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: jar:file:/D:/Programmation/Java/Libraries/javamail-1.4.7/lib/smtp.jar!/META-INF/javamail.address.map
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "mail.protonmail.ch", port 587, isSSL false
421 Cannot connect to SMTP server ::ffff:185.70.40.101 (::ffff:185.70.40.101:587), connect error 10060
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: mail.protonmail.ch, port: 587, response: 421
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1949)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:654)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:317)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:125)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:194)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
    at MailSender.send(MailSender.java:50)
    at Start.main(Start.java:6)
DEBUG SMTP: could not connect to host "mail.protonmail.ch", port: 587, response: 421
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot connect to `mail.protonmail.ch:587` because the service doesn't exist. There is no documentation that this particular SMTP server exists. The `connect error 10060` (which is Connection timed out) you are getting is further proof of that.

If you want to use Protonmail, you will need to use the [ProtonMail Bridge](https://protonmail.com/support/knowledge-base/imap-smtp-and-pop3-setup/). This will then spawn a server socket on localhost, which you then can connect to. See: [Setup Guide](https://protonmail.com/bridge/thunderbird#4)

You can download the Bridge from here: https://protonmail.com/bridge/

Comment: ProtonMail Bridge doesn't exist yet for Linux :-/ . So I'll use gmail for the moment.

Comment: You might also want to upgrade to a newer version of JavaMail; 1.4.7 is pretty old, the current version is [1.6.1](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/).

Comment: As of now I can see there is Proton Mail Bridge available for Linux.